# How can one open a UsbDevice object as a file, similar to UsbAccessory, using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream

Tags: android, file, usb

I'm writing an Android application that interfaces with an attached device using a USB On-the-Go cable and the `android.hardware.usb` library. I want to use the Android device as a host, since using it as an accessory is providing no response from the application, but using it as a `USBDevice` is getting (some) response.

Specifically, a `UsbAccessory` object can be opened as a file as such:

```
UsbManager myUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
UsbAccessory myUsbAccessory = (myUsbManager.getAccessoryList())[0];
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = myUsbManager.openAccessory(myUsbAccessory);
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
FileInputStream myFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
FileOutputStream myFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
```

And then you can read and write to the accessory as you would usually with a file, which is very convenient, needless to say.

However, the same actions aren't available for `UsbDevice`. A `UsbDeviceConnection` is returned by `myUsbManager.openDevice(myUsbDevice)`, instead of a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, which means I can't get the `FileDescriptor` from a `getFileDescriptor()` method. Well, `UsbDeviceConnection` does have a `getFileDescriptor()` method, but it returns, of all things, an int, so I have no idea how to use this as I didn't even get what it does/how it can be of use to me.

I've looked over the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html) a lot and still haven't found any way to do this. My question is: does anyone know/can think up a way to open a FileInput/OutputStream to the UsbDevice so that I can just read/write to it like a normal file?

Comment: That's not going to work.  While a USB device may follow the UNIX "everything is a file" paradigm, it is a *device file* to which you can perform raw USB operations, not a *file system file* to which you could directly read or write file content data.  What is missing is anything that knows about a `file system` or implements `USB Mass Storage Protocol`.  Apps which interact with USB storage devices implement both the file system and the mass storage protocol within their own code, because (with the exception of vendor additions to a few tablets) the Android system does not do that for you.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In that case, is there any way to mimic this? I want a one-liner (after some setup, of course) to be able to send/receive data to/from the UsbDevice, and the Endpoints thing seems convoluted.

Comment: No.  It's simply not supported by the system. Your app has to ship the code to implement endpoint-level operations.  Only if the vendor has set up something so the device mounts USB storage volumes, or you leverage a root hack to get it to can you avoid that - but then you aren't really targetting standard android.

Comment: I've been trying to find the streams interface, that Android Accessory has, and apparently it's not available. I will implement a compatible wrapper to solve my problem. My question is: Most USB generic devices are "USB serial" devices. Some not, but most are serial interface compatible. It would be great if I could DECLARE a device as a "USB Serial"/ Android USB accessory device. Having the file/ streams IO would help a lot for device compatibility reasons. 
Seems to be shallow thinking on USB and devices connectivity. Almost like "Apple way" of limiting interoperability.